# Prove or disprove: If $(q+1)$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($0\le q \le n$) are LI, then they are not contained in any $(q-1)$ dimensional plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can we prove or disprove the following statement:

If $(q+1)$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ($0\le q \le n$) are LI, then they are not contained in any $(q-1)$ dimensional plane.

(The converse of this statement is true.)

Suppose the points are $\{x_i\}_{1 \le i \le q+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let them be LI i.e. $\forall \{ \mu_i\} \sum_i \mu_i x_i = 0 \Rightarrow \mu_i = 0$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: What means *LI* for points?

Comment: linearly independant

Comment: Any $q-1$ dimensional plane will have basis of $q-1$ elements so there can't be $q+1$ linearly indepent

Comment: Obvious for any vectorial space.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi that's only for planes that pass through the origin, otherwise you need you use that you have *2* relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the $q + 1$ points are a basis by replacing $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the span and the $(q-1)$-plane by any $(q-1)$-plane containing its intersection with the span.

Now take the two linear equatations that define the $(q - 1)$-plane and take a non-trivial linear combination that cancels the constant terms. This is a linear dependence.